# tab to next cell in tablesorter with editable and stickeyheaders widgets

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to make a dynamically loaded table use [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/) with both the `editable` and `stickyHeaders` widgets enabled.

I've got it pretty close to working. One weird thing though. If I click in an editable cell then press tab, the next cell is activated but only for a split second then loses focus.

**In Chrome**, the cursor just disappears.

**In Safari**, after the second cell loses focus you can see the cursor jump to the far right of the header row of the table where it sits blinking until you click somewhere else.
Heres a picture showing the cursor in Firefox

[image]

**Here is a striped down version of the demo for the `editable` widget that works as expected:**
[Editable working version](http://pnrbuilder.com/ftpdevtest/tablesorterTest/example-widget-editable.html)

**Here is a striped down version of the demo for the `editable` widget with the `stickyheaders` also added which breaks the tab to next cell feature:**

[Editable + Stickyheaders  not working](http://pnrbuilder.com/ftpdevtest/tablesorterTest/example-widget-editable-stickeyheaders.html)

The only difference is the addition of `Stickyheaders`

---

EDIT:

Ok, the problem seems to be this chunk of code starting at line 885 of `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js`

```
searching: function(table, filter, skipFirst) {
        var wo = table.config.widgetOptions;
        clearTimeout(wo.searchTimer);
        if (typeof filter === 'undefined' || filter === true) {
            // delay filtering
            wo.searchTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                ts.filter.checkFilters(table, filter, skipFirst );
            }, wo.filter_liveSearch ? wo.filter_searchDelay : 10);
        } else {
            // skip delay
            ts.filter.checkFilters(table, filter, skipFirst);
        }
    },
```

If I comment it out as below, tabbing functionality is restored:

```
    searching: function(table, filter, skipFirst) {
        /*var wo = table.config.widgetOptions;
        clearTimeout(wo.searchTimer);
        if (typeof filter === 'undefined' || filter === true) {
            // delay filtering
            wo.searchTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                ts.filter.checkFilters(table, filter, skipFirst );
            }, wo.filter_liveSearch ? wo.filter_searchDelay : 10);
        } else {
            // skip delay
            ts.filter.checkFilters(table, filter, skipFirst);
        }*/
    },
```

---

It seems the above chunk of code is what hides all of the non matches when you search for a value using the inputs at the top of the table. Commenting it out fixes the tab feature but breaks the filtering feature.

Any ideas how I can modify this chunk of code to get the normal tab to next cell working again  with out breaking the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

On line 604 of `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js`, I changed....

**This check:**

```
if (event.type === 'filterReset') {
    c.$table.find('.' + ts.css.filter).add(wo.filter_$externalFilters).val('');
    ts.filter.searching(table, []);
}...
```

**To read:**

```
if (event.which !== 9){
} 
else if (event.type === 'filterReset') {
    c.$table.find('.' + ts.css.filter).add(wo.filter_$externalFilters).val('');
    ts.filter.searching(table, []);
} .....
```

So far, this seems to fix the tab feature without breaking any of the sorting functionality.

(To be fair this may have some as yet unknown side effect)

[Here is a demo of the working version](http://pnrbuilder.com/ftpdevtest/tablesorterTest/example-widget-editable-stickeyheaders-working.html)

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. I think I actually found the culprit though... setting `showProcessing: true` seems to cause the table to lose focus; I guess from adding/removing a class name from the table is causing it to redraw, or something. So no need to modify the widget code.

Comment: @mottie I tried setting `showProcessing: false` and reverting my changes to `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js` but doing so causes a different strange side effect. With this solution, if the table is longer than the browser window, and the user scrolls down and clicks an editable cell,, the cell is activated as expected. However, if you then click a second cell or hit the tab key to move to the next cell, the table scrolls back up to the top. The cell itself is still active but the table scrolls so you cant see the active cell anymore.

Comment: Here's a test page with `showProcessing: false` and the original `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js` : http://pnrbuilder.com/ftpdevtest/tablesorterTest/example-widget-editable-stickeyheaders-mottie.html     Scoll to the bottom of the table and click a cell, then click another cell. The table scrolls to the top. If you scroll back down the cell you click is still active.

Comment: Here's a test page with the change I made to `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js` and leaving `showProcessing: true` http://pnrbuilder.com/ftpdevtest/tablesorterTest/example-widget-editable-stickeyheaders-working.html This way works as expected. Again though my way could have it's own as yet undiscovered side effect

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure that this is the problem, but both the original tablesorter and the newest version of tablesorter are being loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery2.0.3_Plus.js?v2.3.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js?v2.3.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js?v2.3.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tableData.js?v2.3.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="loadTable.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<script src="widget-editable.js"></script>
```

Remove the original, and move "loadTable.js" below the newer version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery2.0.3_Plus.js?v2.3.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js?v2.3.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js?v2.3.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tableData.js?v2.3.0"></script>

<script src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="loadTable.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<script src="widget-editable.js"></script>
```

Also, and I'm not sure why the cursor is behaving that way, set the `editable_columns` option to not include a column that doesn't exist - I'll fix the widget in the next version to properly ignore non-existent columns.

```
editable_columns : [0,1,2,3,4,5] // or use '0-5'
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and nice catch on both of those! I have made those changes (and uploaded the new files to the example). It's still happening though. Have you ever used the editable and `stickyHeaders` together before? My first inclination is to think that it has something to do with the clone of the header row that gets created with the `stickyHeaders` widget but that's just a guess. I'm gonna try this with a more simple example and see if I have the same problem.

Comment: Yeah. I made two copies of the `editable` example and striped out all the docs stuff. On the first one I left it as just `editable` and tabbing works as expected. On the second one I added `stickyheaders` and it breaks the tab feature. They dont seem to wanna play nice together. I update my question with the new simplified examples. Gonna dig a little into `stickyheaders` to see if I can find the conflict.

Comment: I found that `searching: function(table, filter, skipFirst)` is responsible for the loss of focus, but I'm not sure how to modify this to have both the tab to next cell and the filter both work.

Comment: I found a solution was to block the tab key from initiating a search function on the table in `jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js`